# Singular integral operator

Tags: real-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, harmonic-analysis

I am working on a problem involving the Biot-Savart law in fluid dynamics. I found a theorem of singular integral which is intimately related to my research.

Assume that $K(x)$ is a classical Calderon-Zygmund kernel in $\mathbb{R}^{3}$ and $f$ is a smooth function satisfying
\begin{equation}
|f(x)|\leq\frac{1}{(1+r)^{a}} \quad \text{for} \quad 0<a<2,
\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation}
|\nabla f(x)|\leq\frac{1}{(1+r)^{b}} \quad \text{for} \quad 0<b<2,
\end{equation}
where $r=\sqrt{x_{1}^{2}+x_{2}^{2}}$. Decays only appear in horizontal directions. No information on the vertical direction.

Let $Tf(x)=\int K(x-y)f(y)dy$. Then there exists a constant $c_{0}$ such that
\begin{equation}
|Tf(x)|\leq\frac{c_{0}}{(1+r)^{d}},
\end{equation}
where $d$ can be any number strictly less than $min\{a,b\}$.

If you can show me that this theorem is sharp, there is no more problems. Otherwise, my questions:

1. Someone suggested me that this theorem might be able to get improved. Since it is a pointwise or $L^{\infty}$ estimate for the singular integral which was not covered by any existing theory. Is that possible to prove something like $d=\frac{a+b}{2}$ which will bring great help to my project.
2. One may change the second condition i.e.  the horizontal decay of $\nabla f$ or add something new like the decay of $\nabla^{2} f$.

I’m not an expert on harmonic analysis. I am very interested in my question 2. Any suggestions are welcome. Thanks!

Comment: The estimate looks rather fishy, as written: consider the case when $a=b$ and $f$ that is essentially $1/r^a$ times the characteristic function of the cylinder $x_1^2+x_2^2\le r^2$ with large $r$ (you need just length $1$ to descend to $0$ with your gradient restriction). Then for the points slightly outside the cylinder, you have all function on one side, so the oscillation in the kernel does not help and you get at least $r^{-a}\log r$ integrating the distance from the point to the power $-3$. What am I missing?

Comment: @fedja It is not clear to me. Are you taking one function or a family? And if $r=\sqrt {x_1^2+x_2^2}$, which is the cylinder? Thank you.

Comment: @GiorgioMetafune Yeah, my using the same $r$ notation as in the OP is confusing, indeed. Replace it by capital $R$ and view it as a family of functions. The point is that the declared estimate cannot hold without logarithmic correction though the example I gave is almost the worst case scenario.

Comment: @fedja Thanks. But replace $r$ by $R$ only in the definition of the cylinder or everywhere or...? By the way, even if the estimate were true, I do not believe it can be improved to the average of $a,b$. This does not happen when the function decays in all directions.

Comment: @fedja Yes, you are correct. There is a log factor on the numerator. I have edited my question. More comments are welcome!

Comment: Could you give a reference for the estimate you quote?

Comment: @GiorgioMetafune Please read Lemma 3.2 of the paper arxiv 1801.07420. https://arxiv.org/pdf/1801.07420.pdf